# Not able to update PostgreSQL database table from PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

The following query works in PostgreSQL but when I run it through php, it doesn't update.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?  It's my first time with PostgreSQL.

```
<?php 
  $connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypw");

 $sql = "UPDATE forum SET views = FLOOR(80 + RANDOM() * 61) where views < 10";

    pg_close($connection); // Close this connection 
?>
```

Comment: I don't see where your query is executed?

Comment: I tried this after the $sql line.  Shouldn't this do it?
$result = pg_query($connection, $sql);

Comment: Add some debugging along the way, such as a `die("Error!")` message after the attempt to connect.  You will also need to execute the query using `pg_query()` (that can use a `die()` message, too).  You can also use `echo pg_last_error($connection)` to get raw error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
$result = pg_query($connection, $sql);
```

If that doesn't work, something could be adding `BEGIN` messages.  In that case add:

```
pg_query($connection, 'COMMIT');
```

Before disconnecting....